# How to shift columns with their properties in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, shift

so i have some code that outputs this on a spreasheet:
[image]

what i want is that you see those empty columns i need them to be gone and have all the columns beside each other to save space.
so is there a way for me to check if a column is empty and if it is i need to pretty much cut and paste the next bunch of columns onto the empty ones WITH their properties such as color code and border.

any help is much appreciated, and thnx in advance. ^_^ :D

Answer (score 0):

Try `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns( *REF* ))`, replacing * REF * with the reference to each column (e.g. using variable and looping through)

If this = 0, the column is empty.

You can then just delete the empty columns, e.g. using `If... Then` in your loop.
(Have a look at:
http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-rows-columns/   for example)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wkSht As Worksheet

    Set wkSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")    '--> enter your sheet name here
    Set rng = wkSht.Range("A:Z")    '--> set your range here
    For i = rng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
       If Application.CountA(Columns(i).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
       Columns(i).Delete
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can also **delete all the empty columns together** using union as:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim rng As Range, delRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wkSht As Worksheet

    Set wkSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")    '--> enter your sheet name here
    Set rng = wkSht.Range("A:Z")    '--> set your range here
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If Application.CountA(Columns(i).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = Columns(i)
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(delRng, Columns(i))
            End If
       End If
    Next i
    delRng.Delete    '--> delete all empty columns
End Sub
```

Comment: @GhaithHaddad - Did this help?